# lightbox not opening after once being closed without page refresh

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am using a lightbox in which i am calling the lightbox after the ajax call so that it can load the new page in lightbox. everything works fine when i click on the link that makes the ajax call once and then open the lightbox first time . Since i have a user input to check if user enters a value below then 7 then only open the ligthbox . So there is a chance that user might end up selecting a value less then 7 and lightbox gives a popup message to select more then 7 . when i close the lightbox and again select any value then it gives e error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'lightbox'
```

As i said it works for the first time and even when i refresh page and try again , but when i close lightbox and click on link to check and open lightbox it gives error . My function is

```
$(document).on("click", ".forwardme", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var confident_monthly_goal = $("#SliderSingle").val();

    if (confident_monthly_goal <= 7) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $php_path; ?>update_goal.php?confident_monthly_goal=" + confident_monthly_goal,
            success: function (html) {

                var html = "twl.php";
                $.lightbox(html, {
                    width: 400,
                    height: 300
                });

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to rebound the lightbox after ajax call.

Comment: ohh ok i understood what you wanted to say . I just tried it right now and it works thanks .